# The variable is being used without being initialized

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I tried to use friend function but facing some issue while passing object as argument to function

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class  base
{
    int val1,val2;
   public:
       //base(){}
    void get()
    {
       cout<<"Enter two values:";
       cin>>val1>>val2;
    }
    friend int mean(base ob);
};
int mean(base ob)
{
   return (ob.val1+ob.val2)/2;
}
int main()
{
    base obj;
    cout<<"\n Mean value is : "<<mean(obj);
    system("pause");
    return 0 ;
}
```

Error:Run time error

Comment: Looks like the answer is in the title, you probably forgot to call `get`, or meant to make it the constructor.

Answer (score 4):

The (compiler generated) default constructor for base does not initialise the data members. So you are not initialising variables val1 and val2 prior to their use.

The behaviour of your program is undefined. Your compiler is being particularly helpful.

A simple remedy would be to supply a default constructor, using base member initialisation to initialise val1 and val2.

Answer (score 0):

You did not define the default constructor. So the compiler defined it itself. It does not initialize data members when you define an object of the class with automatic storage duration like

```
base obj;
```

However you could value-initialize the data memebrs if you would define the object the following way:)

```
base obj = base();
```

In this case `val1` and `val2` will be equal to 0.

Or you could after the definition of the object call its member function `get`

```
base obj;

obj.get();
```